# React Router v4 `Match` rendering unintended components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create basic *RESTful routes* with React Router *v4*, and after going through the docs a few times this is what I came up with.

What's happening is that paths such as `/venues/new` also matches to `/venues/:id`, as it reads it as a dynamic parameter.

I've tried using Match with and without `exactly`, typed out the entire pathname rather than interpolating the value from props, all gives the same behavior.

From my Rails days, I remember the router catching the *first* match, but I'm not sure how to get around these multiple matches for standard RESTful routes. Thanks for any input!

```
render() {
  const { pathname } = this.props;
  return (<div>
    <h1>VENUES</h1>
    <Link to={`${pathname}/new`}><button>New Venue</button></Link>

    <Match exactly pattern={`${pathname}`} render={(mprops) => (<VenueList {...mprops} venues={venues} />)} />
    <Match exactly pattern={`${pathname}/new`} render={() => (<VenueNew onSubmit={this.addVenue} />)} />
    <Match exactly pattern={`${pathname}/:id/edit`} render={(mprops) => (<Venue {...mprops} venue={venue} edit={true} />)} />
    <Match exactly pattern={`${pathname}/:id`} render={(mprops) => (<Venue {...mprops} venue={venues} />)} />
    <Miss render={() => (<h3>No Route</h3>)} />
  </div>);
}
```

Comment: This usecase should be what you're looking for https://react-router.now.sh/ambiguous-matches

Comment: Wow, no idea how I missed this in the docs.. but that's exactly what I needed! Thanks for the quick response @erichardson30! 

Comment: No problem. And welcome to SO

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! :D